# Trying to convert Datetime to a certain format yyyymmddHHmmss

Tags: apex, callout

If System.now() returns 2021-09-06 19:50:23
and the output string that I want to send is 20210906195023
for some reason I tried capturing this datetime as a string but to force a format messes up the whole timestamp that I am trying to capture

for instance I want to remove the ( - , spaces , : ) from the datetime output but replace, replace all with regex do not work on that output for some reason, if I convert it to string with string.valueOfGmt it will convert the timezone which isn't the right value that I am looking for

I tried:

```
Datetime now = Datetime.now();
Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
system.debug('time is '+local);

system.debug('time after editing '+local.format('yyyymmddHHmmss'));
```

for some reason the date is messed up when I do this, the reason I need this is that the JSON that i am required to send has a timestamp of this format without dashes,colons or spaces and it can't be changed from their end

Comment: Is it supposed to be in GMT or some other time zone?

Comment: i wanted it to be Denver time, so I took that format yyyyMMddHHmmss
string mydate=Datetime.now().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss');
my default settings has Denver Mountain time so It worked
thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for formatGMT:

```
String output = DateTime.now().formatGMT('yyyyMMddHHmmss');
System.debug(output);
```

Note that `MM` is month, while `mm` is minute. This will give you the format you're looking for in GMT (GMT-00:00).

You can read [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all available options.